# We need options to view long code lines more easily

Tags: discussion

Scrolling is required to view the end of longish code lines. Even on the widest monitors, there's no flexibility. We could make the code field grab-able/expandable with the size limitation being the displayed page size minus margins. Or maybe have a raw code view that shows the code in another view. What do you think?

Comment: OP's have the option to write shorter code lines, eg. one argument/parameter per line with complex function/method calls.

Comment: Please don't destroy my question quality indicator.

Comment: If the code is one-liner you have the option to post inline code, which has line wrap but not syntax highlighting. Particularly relevant for C code on [codegolf.se].

Comment: @HansPassant lol, there are plenty more to go at.  You've been on SO for some time and, like me, I'm sure you can identify bad questions from just the title 99% of the time:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we need to <s>knock the OP upside the head and tell them not to post their ENTIRE project</s> close the question as "unclear what you're asking" until the question and its provided code can be edited down to a necessary fragment.  Posting lots of code unnecessarily which *can* cause scrolling is not useful for anyone looking at the question.

In answers it's a bit different since answers can be a bit more complex and require more lines of code, but it's been very rare that I've seen that be an actual *problem*.  You normally see this in questions.

Comment: Some users seem to think that it's madatory to call functions with 14 arguments using only one line:(

Comment: @MartinJames:  If you have fourteen arguments to your function, i͘͞҉͓̬͇͓̦̻͉t̗̣̀͞ ̶͖̺̜̠͉͔i̳͎͕̼̪͞s̡̱͇͜͝ ̀҉͍̟̻̻̳̻͙ṱ̴̸̳̣̲̫̘o̸̦̟̥͚͉o̴̡̨͕̬̯̯̲͈͎ͅ ҉̷̥l̷̢̹̥̭͈͘a̙t̶͎͙̳̖̱͘e̝̻̠̭͇̹͡ ̶̥̮̮̘̩͎͕̩̠͠Ḫ̨̫̣̗͔̖͚̫́͜E̡̢͏̰̤̭͈̹͎ ̳̟̝͈̲C̶͔̼͓̗͘̕O̬͓̬͙͢͠M̸̯̣̖̘̬͚̞͟E̶̢͇̝̜̠S̢̜̺̙̪̣̙̺

Comment: lol, I was thinking of behemoth OS API calls, not my own code:)

Comment: @Makoto ok I can see that. I'd still like a raw button, but whatever.